# why the html code sent by controller displays in my page?

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I work by `ecommerce` site, and I want to test the `quantity` of `product` (annonce), if the `qty = 0` display `Not Avialable` in danger color, if `qty <= 5` display `low Stock` in  color if `qty > 5` display `in Stock` in success color.
in my example it displays in my html code page.

**AnnoncesController.php**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $annonces = Annonce::where('id',$id)->firstOrfail();
        $mightAlsoLike = Annonce::where('id', '!=', $id)->mightAlsoLike()->get();

        if( $annonces->quantity > setting('site.stock_threshold') ){
            $stockLevel = '<div class="badge badge-pill badge-success">in stock</div>';
        } elseif($annonces->quantity <= setting('site.stock_threshold') && $annonces->quantity > 0) {
            $stockLevel = '<div class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">low stock</div>';
        }else {
            $stockLevel = '<div class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">Not Avialable</div>';
        }

         return view('annonces.details')->with([
             'annonces'      => $annonces,
             'stockLevel'    => $stockLevel, 
             'mightAlsoLike' => $mightAlsoLike
            ]);
    }
```

**details.blade.php**

```
<div>{{ $stockLevel }}</div>
```

[image: details page]

Comment: Surely because the value of $stockLevel is automatically converted to HTML entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to display the complied html you can use the below syntax and docs can be found [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data)

```
<div>{!! $stockLevel !!}</div>
```

Or You can use `HtmlString` class

```
<div>{{new Illuminate\Support\HtmlString($stockLevel )}}</div>
```

**and be careful with XSS vulnerability**

Or you can pass data from Controller

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $stockLevelStatus = $stockLevelBadge = null;
        $annonces = Annonce::where('id', $id)->firstOrfail();
        $mightAlsoLike = Annonce::where('id', '!=', $id)->mightAlsoLike()->get();

        if ($annonces->quantity > setting('site.stock_threshold')) {
            $stockLevelStatus = 'In Stock';
            $stockLevelBadge = 'badge-success';
        } elseif ($annonces->quantity <= setting('site.stock_threshold') && $annonces->quantity > 0) {
            $stockLevelStatus = 'Low Stock';
            $stockLevelBadge = 'badge-warning';
        } else {
            $stockLevelStatus = 'Not Avialable';
            $stockLevelBadge = 'badge-danger';
        }

        return view('annonces.details')->with([
            'annonces' => $annonces,
            'stockLevelStatus'  => $stockLevelStatus,
            'stockLevelBadge' => $stockLevelBadge,
            'mightAlsoLike' => $mightAlsoLike,
        ]);
    }
```

balde:

```
<div>
  <div class="badge badge-pill {{$stockLevelBadge}}"> 
   {{$stockLevelStatus}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{!! $stockLevel !!}
```

try this. it is worked forme

Comment: If you answer a question, don't just say "try this", but explain your answer.

Comment: Cause when you send html {{ !!  !!}} use this if you use {{ $stockLevel }} it read a text.

Comment: No, Because `{{ }}`escapes the html , and `{!! !!}` is a raw echo. Using `{!! !!}` is not recommended on user input because you are open to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
{!! $stockLevel !!}
```

**BUT I DO NOT RECOMMEND IT**. By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS attacks. Better to make conditional through Blade :

```
@if($annonces->quantity > setting('site.stock_threshold'))
    <div class="badge badge-pill badge-success">in stock</div>
@elseif($annonces->quantity <= setting('site.stock_threshold') && $annonces->quantity > 0)
    <div class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">low stock</div>
@else
    <div class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">Not Avialable</div>
@endif
```